# Filter Constituents on "Do not trade?"

Tags: contacts, reports, privacy

Before I add a custom field to handle this, I thought I'd make sure I'm not missing something.

When I go to Contact Reports -> Constituent Summary, it appears you can include and filter on all the "Do not" privacy settings EXCEPT "Do not trade."

Is there a way to add the ability to filter on "Do not trade?" Any idea why that one in particular is left out?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Matt. Did you manage to achieve this in your report? Would you mind sharing how you have done it please? I am in a similar situation.... thanks

Comment: Hi Tapash -- I wound up adding a custom field and making that searchable. I have since migrated to Salesforce so I didn't dig deeper into how to do this with the native CiviCRM functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People build reports based on their clients requirement and if they think this is going to help others in the community they contribute code either in the form of sending PR to core or release as an extension publicly.

I think (but not confident) [Extended reports extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) does provides some additional filtering and reports, its worth trying if it meets your need. Else you can use [alterReportVar](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/) hook to add filter to reports.

Hope i answered your question!

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep -- the Extended reports extension didn't seem to address that from what I could tell, and I'm trying to keep the project I'm working on as stock as possible, so I just added a custom field to handle it and made that searchable, and that seemed to do the trick. I appreciate the information both about the extension and the alterReportVar bit -- I may look into that in the future. Thanks again.